# How to get mongo db document size limit for 'find' query?

Tags: java, mongodb

It looks pretty odd question but let me explain further, I need to query mongodb collection and get documents. The collection size is in TB. I have to do some operation on set of documents periodically (lets say after every 2 hrs). Operation is quite simple find documents (as per criteria), and copy to another collection and delete from original collection.The problem is I can't decide(not aware) what will size of documents to retrieve. I am using MongoTemplate(I have to go with this). I am sure that size of documents must be less than RAM. But still what is the procedure to get exact size of document so I wont get any timeout or out of space error.

Comment: if you write documents to an other collection using a **`$out`** stage in an aggregation query, documents size can exceed RAM, you just need to set `allowDiskUse` parameter to true

Comment: Hey. As I can put limit on number of documents to retrieve from collection and process those for better performance. How to calculate that limit so memory will not go out of space. Did you get my point? 
Lets take an example of my desktop with 16GB Ram and 64 bit processor.

Answer (score 0):

I think it fulfilled your purpose-

```
Object.bsonsize(db.students.find())
Object.bsonsize(db.students.findOne({*condition*}))
```

It return the size of the particular document (in bytes).

Comment: Hey. I know the size of collection. I want to calculate number of documents to fetch from collection and process for better performance. What procedure  I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

The maximum object size of one mongo object is 16MB. I assume handling 16MB should be no problem for your system. Hence you get one object from the source collection and copy it to the target collection.

For queries that return a number of results use a cursor to iterate over each result and copy it result for result into the new collection.